# Finding elements in a jQuery accordion before activate for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery accordion setup as follows:

```
var checkout = $('#bookingaccordion').accordion({
    header: 'h3.header',
    heightStyle: 'content',
    collapsible: false

});
```

I want to validate each panel of the accordion before the user moves onto the next. I have each form field setup with a `required` attribute (HTML5). Using the `accordionbeforeactivate` event I want to loop through the inputs in the corresponding panel and flag up if there is a required field and stop the next panel being displayed.

So far I have:

```
checkout.on('accordionbeforeactivate', function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.oldPanel).each(function(index,element) {
        if($(element).prop('required')) {
            console.log($(this).prop('name'));
//Validation and if fails, stop next panel
        }
    })
});
```

But I'm not seeing anything in the console. I'm sure my issue is just how I'm handling `ui` but can't figure it out.

HTML structure is:

```
<div class="accordion ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" id="bookingaccordion" role="tablist">
    <h3 class="header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" role="tab" id="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-header-0" aria-controls="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-panel-0" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Party Guest &amp; Cost Information</h3>
    <div class="pane pane1 ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-panel-0" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-header-0" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-row form-inline">
                <label for="partybags">Party Bags (5 items) @ £<span class="costvalue">5</span> each bag:<br>(plus carriage)</label>
                <input type="number" name="partybags" id="partybags" min="0" required>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <h3 class="header ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" id="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-header-1" aria-controls="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-panel-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Party Details</h3>
    <div class="pane pane2 ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" id="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-panel-1" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-bookingaccordion-header-1" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Party Details</legend>
            <div class="form-row form-inline">
                <label for="agerange">Age Range:</label>
                <input type="text" name="agerange" id="agerange" required="" placeholder="eg. 6 - 7 year olds " required>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share the sample html... you might need to change `$(ui.oldPanel).each(...)` to `$(ui.oldPanel).find('input').each(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I can see is, you are trying to loop `ui.oldPanel` which will contain only the wrapper panel reference but instead you want to iterate through all the input elements within it so

```
checkout.on('accordionbeforeactivate', function (event, ui) {
    $(ui.oldPanel).find('input').each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).prop('required')) {
            console.log($(this).prop('name'));
            //Validation and if fails, stop next panel
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: This now picks up the element correctly. Excellent! How can I stop the accordion moving to the next panel if the validation fails?

Comment: @Jeepstone you can call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action